# responsive flexbox footer does not fill the screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using a responsive flexbox footer that works fine on its own on codepen but doesn't fill the screen when i add it to my code, i have changed alot of things but it doesn't still fill the screen, it still shows the left and right border line. i think something is overriding the footer css. [image]

```css
       body {
        font-family: Assistant;
        background: url('vector 1.png') no-repeat right top #D2F4E0;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .container {
        max-width: 1005px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 2em 1 em;
    }
    
    .header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #navy-logo {
        width: 180px;
    }
    
    nav {
        margin: 2em auto 0;
        max-width: 600px;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    nav ul li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 1.25em;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    main {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
    
    .hero {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .hero h1 {
        font-size: 2.5 em;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #056F5B;
    }
    
    .hero p {
        font-size: 1.2 em;
        font-weight: 600;
        max-width: 500px;
        line-height: 1.8em;
        margin: 3em auto;
    }
    
    .hero p:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 120px;
        border: 2px solid #ffff;
        margin 1em auto;
    }
    
    .hero a {
        background: #1B7E43;
        padding: 0.5em 2em;
        border-radius: 9px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.375em;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    figure {
        text-align: centre
    }
    
    figure img {
        margin: 3em auto 0;
        width: 300px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width:820px) {
        header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-flow: wrap;
            align-self: center;
        }
        nav {
            margin: 0;
        }
        nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
        }
        nav ul li {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0.5em 2em;
        }
        nav ul li a {
            font-size: 1.375em;
            color: black;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .wakee {
            border: 3px solid rgb(55, 255, 98);
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        main {
            flex-flow: row;
        }
        .hero {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .hero h1 {
            font-size: 4em;
        }
        .hero p:before {
            margin: 1em 0;
        }
        .hero p {
            font-size: 1.3em;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 0 3em 0;
            color: black;
        }
        .hero a {
            background: #;
        }
    }
    
    
    }
    /
    /* FOOTER */
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    footer {
        background-color: #F3F8F5;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
    footer a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .ft-title {
        color: #333;
        font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
        font-size: 1.375rem;
        padding-bottom: 0.625rem;
    }
    
    /* Sticks footer to bottom */
    .containeer {
        flex: 1;
    }
    
    /* Footer main */
    .ft-main {
        padding: 1.25rem 1.875rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 29.8125rem/* 477px */
    ) {
        .ft-main {
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:820px) {
        .ft-main {
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
    }
    .ft-main-item {
        padding: 1.25rem;
        min-width: 12.5rem;
    }
    
    /* Footer main | Newsletter form */
    form {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    input[type="email"] {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0.625rem;
        margin-top: 0.3125rem;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
        background-color: #00d188;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0.625rem 0.9375rem;
        margin-top: 0.3125rem;
    }
    
    /* Footer social */
    .ft-social {
        padding: 0 1.875rem 1.25rem;
    }
    .ft-social-list {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        border-top: 1px #777 solid;
        padding-top: 1.25rem;
    }
    .ft-social-list li {
        margin: 0.5rem;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="newcss.css" rel=" stylesheet ">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="container">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li class="wakee"><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main class="container">
            <section class="hero container">
                <h1>website test code test</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Elementum suspendisse venenatis nibh nibh cras. Et porttitor amet ac iaculis pharetra. Eu sagittis adipiscing etiam tellus feugiat quis cursus cras orci.</p>
                <a href="#">Get Started</a>
            </section>
            <div class="device">
                <figure>
                    <img src="Vectord.svg" class="svgtest" alt=" logo">
                </figure>
            </div>

        </main>
        <div class="containeer"></div>
        <footer>
            <!-- Footer main -->
            <section class="ft-main">
                <div class="ft-main-item">
                    <h2 class="ft-title">About</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ft-main-item">
                    <h2 class="ft-title">Resources</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">eBooks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Webinars</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ft-main-item">
                    <h2 class="ft-title">Contact</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ft-main-item">
                    <h2 class="ft-title">Stay Updated</h2>
                    <p>Subscribe to our newsletter to get our latest news.</p>
                    <form>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
                        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- Footer social -->
            <section class="ft-social">
                <ul class="ft-social-list">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>


        </footer>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: add in your css:- body { padding: 0; margin: 0;}

Comment: The image looks as if you had some `padding` either on body or on some other wrapper element between `body` and `footer` (which contains the footer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

```css
  body {
    font-family: Assistant;
    background: url('vector 1.png') no-repeat right top #D2F4E0;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1005px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em 1 em;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
}

#navy-logo {
    width: 180px;
}

nav {
    margin: 2em auto 0;
    max-width: 600px;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.hero {
    text-align: center;
}

.hero h1 {
    font-size: 2.5 em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #056F5B;
}

.hero p {
    font-size: 1.2 em;
    font-weight: 600;
    max-width: 500px;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    margin: 3em auto;
}

.hero p:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    border: 2px solid #ffff;
    margin 1em auto;
}

.hero a {
    background: #1B7E43;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    border-radius: 9px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.375em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

figure {
    text-align: centre
}

figure img {
    margin: 3em auto 0;
    width: 300px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:820px) {
    header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-flow: wrap;
        align-self: center;
    }
    nav {
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
    }
    nav ul li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0.5em 2em;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 1.375em;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .wakee {
        border: 3px solid rgb(55, 255, 98);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    main {
        flex-flow: row;
    }
    .hero {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .hero h1 {
        font-size: 4em;
    }
    .hero p:before {
        margin: 1em 0;
    }
    .hero p {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 0 3em 0;
        color: black;
    }
    .hero a {
        background: #;
    }
}


}
/
/* FOOTER */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
footer {
    background-color: #F3F8F5;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.ft-title {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
    font-size: 1.375rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.625rem;
}

/* Sticks footer to bottom */
.containeer {
    flex: 1;
}

/* Footer main */
.ft-main {
    padding: 1.25rem 1.875rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 29.8125rem/* 477px */
) {
    .ft-main {
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:820px) {
    .ft-main {
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
}
.ft-main-item {
    padding: 1.25rem;
    min-width: 12.5rem;
}

/* Footer main | Newsletter form */
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
input[type="email"] {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0.625rem;
    margin-top: 0.3125rem;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #00d188;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0.625rem 0.9375rem;
    margin-top: 0.3125rem;
}

/* Footer social */
.ft-social {
    padding: 0 1.875rem 1.25rem;
}
.ft-social-list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: 1px #777 solid;
    padding-top: 1.25rem;
}
.ft-social-list li {
    margin: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="newcss.css" rel=" stylesheet ">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <header class="container">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li class="wakee"><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="container">
        <section class="hero container">
            <h1>website test code test</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Elementum suspendisse venenatis nibh nibh cras. Et porttitor amet ac iaculis pharetra. Eu sagittis adipiscing etiam tellus feugiat quis cursus cras orci.</p>
            <a href="#">Get Started</a>
        </section>
        <div class="device">
            <figure>
                <img src="Vectord.svg" class="svgtest" alt=" logo">
            </figure>
        </div>

    </main>
    <div class="containeer"></div>
    <footer>
        <!-- Footer main -->
        <section class="ft-main">
            <div class="ft-main-item">
                <h2 class="ft-title">About</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ft-main-item">
                <h2 class="ft-title">Resources</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">eBooks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Webinars</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ft-main-item">
                <h2 class="ft-title">Contact</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ft-main-item">
                <h2 class="ft-title">Stay Updated</h2>
                <p>Subscribe to our newsletter to get our latest news.</p>
                <form>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Footer social -->
        <section class="ft-social">
            <ul class="ft-social-list">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>


    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `body` `margin` to `0`

```css
  body {
    font-family: Assistant;
    background: url('vector 1.png') no-repeat right top #D2F4E0;
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1005px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em 1 em;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
}

#navy-logo {
    width: 180px;
}

nav {
    margin: 2em auto 0;
    max-width: 600px;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.hero {
    text-align: center;
}

.hero h1 {
    font-size: 2.5 em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #056F5B;
}

.hero p {
    font-size: 1.2 em;
    font-weight: 600;
    max-width: 500px;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    margin: 3em auto;
}

.hero p:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    border: 2px solid #ffff;
    margin 1em auto;
}

.hero a {
    background: #1B7E43;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    border-radius: 9px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.375em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

figure {
    text-align: centre
}

figure img {
    margin: 3em auto 0;
    width: 300px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:820px) {
    header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-flow: wrap;
        align-self: center;
    }
    nav {
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
    }
    nav ul li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0.5em 2em;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 1.375em;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .wakee {
        border: 3px solid rgb(55, 255, 98);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    main {
        flex-flow: row;
    }
    .hero {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .hero h1 {
        font-size: 4em;
    }
    .hero p:before {
        margin: 1em 0;
    }
    .hero p {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 0 3em 0;
        color: black;
    }
    .hero a {
        background: #;
    }
}


}
/
/* FOOTER */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
footer {
    background-color: #F3F8F5;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.ft-title {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
    font-size: 1.375rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.625rem;
}

/* Sticks footer to bottom */
.containeer {
    flex: 1;
}

/* Footer main */
.ft-main {
    padding: 1.25rem 1.875rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 29.8125rem/* 477px */
) {
    .ft-main {
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:820px) {
    .ft-main {
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
}
.ft-main-item {
    padding: 1.25rem;
    min-width: 12.5rem;
}

/* Footer main | Newsletter form */
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
input[type="email"] {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0.625rem;
    margin-top: 0.3125rem;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #00d188;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0.625rem 0.9375rem;
    margin-top: 0.3125rem;
}

/* Footer social */
.ft-social {
    padding: 0 1.875rem 1.25rem;
}
.ft-social-list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: 1px #777 solid;
    padding-top: 1.25rem;
}
.ft-social-list li {
    margin: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="newcss.css" rel=" stylesheet ">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <header class="container">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li class="wakee"><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="container">
        <section class="hero container">
            <h1>website test code test</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Elementum suspendisse venenatis nibh nibh cras. Et porttitor amet ac iaculis pharetra. Eu sagittis adipiscing etiam tellus feugiat quis cursus cras orci.</p>
            <a href="#">Get Started</a>
        </section>
        <div class="device">
            <figure>
                <img src="Vectord.svg" class="svgtest" alt=" logo">
            </figure>
        </div>

    </main>
    <div class="containeer"></div>
    <footer>
        <!-- Footer main -->
        <section class="ft-main">
            <div class="ft-main-item">
                <h2 class="ft-title">About</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ft-main-item">
                <h2 class="ft-title">Resources</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">eBooks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Webinars</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ft-main-item">
                <h2 class="ft-title">Contact</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ft-main-item">
                <h2 class="ft-title">Stay Updated</h2>
                <p>Subscribe to our newsletter to get our latest news.</p>
                <form>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Footer social -->
        <section class="ft-social">
            <ul class="ft-social-list">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>


    </footer>
</body>
```